# Just learned about exceptions in Javascript. Need help better understanding

Tags: javascript, exception

```
function MultiplicatorUnitFailure() {}

function primitiveMultiply(a, b) {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5)
    return a * b;
  else
    throw new MultiplicatorUnitFailure();
}

function reliableMultiply(a, b) {
  var x;
  try {x = primitiveMultiply(a, b);}
      catch(error){  
        if (error instanceof MultiplicatorUnitFailure) 
           x = primitiveMultiply(a,b);
        else 
        throw error;
      }
   return x;

}
```

Hi everybody!  Just finished the eloquent javascript chapter on expressions.  Was given faulty function primitive Multiple that returns a valid multiplication of parameters a and b half of the time, and the other half throw an exception of type MultiplicatorUnitFailure, a custom built exception.  I am asked to make reliable multiple multiply 2 numbers a and b correctly 100% of the time by calling primitive multiply until it doesnt throw me a MultiplicatorUnitFailure error.  If it throws any other error I am to give up and throw that error. I filled in my code but at times am getting [object Object] in my console.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably seeing an exception thrown from the second call to `primitiveMultiply` which isn't inside a try block. Try removing this call and instead putting a loop around the first call like:

```
function reliableMultiply(a, b) {
    var x;
    while(!x) {
        try {
            x = primitiveMultiply(a, b);
        } catch(error) {
            if (!error instanceof MultiplicatorUnitFailure) {
                throw error;
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```